# Missing new user flag in token claim: Azure B2C

Tags: bearer-token, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2c, claims-authentication

We created Sign Up and Sign In userflow for our B2C application to authenticate users.

To identify the user selected option i.e, sign up or sign in, we added "User is new" application claim to our user flow:

[image]

But when we generate the token, we cannot see "newUser" flag in it's claims.

[image]

```
"iss": "https://ourb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/0006565e-bfe8-45ee-a405-cede36487a6d/v2.0/",
"exp": 1666757889,
"nbf": 1666754289,
"aud": "3df6735e-2c7c-436d-a9f2-058d213d125a",
"tfp": "B2C_1_SUSI",
"azpacr": "1",
"sub": "92769eb0-14f3-40f8-bef8-75fef429214c".
"oid": "92769eb0-14f3-40f8-bef8-75fef429214c",
"tid": "0006565e-bfe8-45ee-a405-cede36487a6d",
"ver": "2.0",
"azp": "3df6735e-2c7c-436d-a9f2-058d213d125a".
"iat": 1666754289
```

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use interactive method like ***authorization code flow*** and include **openid** scope to get `new user` token claim.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have one Azure AD B2C application that has **supported account type** as below:

[image]

Now I created one `Sign up and sign in` user flow with same parameters as you and ran the user flow like below:

[image]

When I ran the user flow, I got the **login screen** like below:

[image]

Now I selected `Sign up now` to sign in as a **new user** and got below screen where I filled **details** like this:

[image]

When I selected ***Create***, it took me to the redirect URI with **`code`** in address bar like below:

[image]

To generate access token, I used **authorization code** flow with parameters like below:

```http
POST https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appid
client_secret:secret
scope:openid 
code: use the code that you got in above step
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token, I got **`newUser`** claim as true as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, changing to authorization code flow + openid did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It only sends the newUser claim when the value is true (after initial user sign up). Notice the Description column of the "User is new" row on the Application claims screen - *True, if the user has just signed-up for your application*.

Here are token claims after initial sign up:

```
  "exp": 1666934066,
  "nbf": 1666930466,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://circleboxb2c.b2clogin.com/6e16d329-4657-4f68-bbbe-e47f06bb97c3/v2.0/",
  "sub": "c22da3c0-df8c-4d4e-9ca2-0f9004994b13",
  "aud": "61d2758f-7210-4e72-a669-915583ace4f9",
  "nonce": "638025272161383928.NTVhOWZjOTAtMGI5Yy00NGEyLTg3MzUtNjI2YzQxNjk4ZDdmMzMzNjZhOTItYmM3OC00NDFlLWEzMzItODVjNDVhZjk0Zjc4",
  "iat": 1666930466,
  "auth_time": 1666930466,
  "newUser": true,
  "tfp": "B2C_1_susi-so"
```

When I logout and sign in with that user, I get these claims (no newUser claim this time):

```
  "exp": 1666933847,
  "nbf": 1666930247,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://circleboxb2c.b2clogin.com/6e16d329-4657-4f68-bbbe-e47f06bb97c3/v2.0/",
  "sub": "bd9abfd8-5d79-4231-ad48-5a7b8c700e0f",
  "aud": "61d2758f-7210-4e72-a669-915583ace4f9",
  "nonce": "638025270465287700.Y2FjZjZkMzgtMjBhMC00OWE2LWFjNzQtOGUzMzZkNmQ2NjZjNWFhM2NjMDMtZTNhYi00MWU4LThjYjItZWVjNmVmNmU4MDM2",
  "iat": 1666930247,
  "auth_time": 1666930247,
  "tfp": "B2C_1_susi-so"
```

Comment: User signed up for first time, changing to authorization code flow worked